# R using list variables in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have variables from a list (year, class size, and tuition) that I would like to join in a table and then create a time series plot using year and class size. However, when I use ggplot, an error says it doesn't know how to deal with list data. Here's my code:

```
univ.ann <- results1[c(as.character(1996:2015))]

size <- sapply(univ.ann, function(LIST) LIST$student$size) %>% 
  unlist()

size_df <- data.frame(classsize = size) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "year") 

tuition <- sapply(univ.ann, function(LIST) LIST$cost$tuition$in_state) %>% 
  unlist()

tuition_df <- data.frame(in_state = tuition) %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "year") 

full_join(size_df, tuition_df, by = c("year" = "year")) %>% 
  arrange(year)
```

Everything at this point works, however, a plot fails to show up when I execute the following code chunk:

```
university_plot <- ggplot(univ.ann, aes(year)) + 
  geom_point(aes(y=size_df)) + 
  ylab("Size") + 
  xlab("Year") + 
  ggtitle("Class Size Plot")

university_plot
```

Is there a way to use ggplot for list variables?

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run and test the code. ggplot exists `data.frames` or `tibbles` or things that can be coerced to either. Generic lists are not allowed (but you can probably convert it yourself with `as.data.frame()`).

Comment: What is `results1`??

Comment: @Prradep results1 is a table showing the class size and tuition from 1996 to 2015.